# converting couple of lists into list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

My issue is simple I want to convert couple of lists into list of lists:

Here is an example of the data:

```
 ['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1']
 ['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2']
 ['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3']
 ['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4']
```

I have tried this code:

```
lignes = data.split('\n')
lst =[[i]  for i in lignes]  
print(lst)
```

It gives me this result:

```
[["['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1']"],
 ["['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2']"],
 ["['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3']"],
 ["['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4']"]]
```

The result I want to have is:

```
[['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1'],
 ['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2'],
 ['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3'],
 ['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4']]
```

If you have any idea how I can solve this issue please help.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is just a long string in form:

```
data = """['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1']
['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2']
['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3']
['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4']"""
```

First, you can split this into separate rows, then use split again to get output in a format that allows you to create list from each row and at the end append to the list you want to create:

```
data_splt = data.split('\n')
output = []
for i in range(len(data_splt)):
    temp = data_splt[i].split("'")[1:6:2]
    output.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
[['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1'],
 ['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2'],
 ['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3'],
 ['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4']]
```

EDIT:
Or even better, using a list comprehension:

```
data_splt = data.split('\n')
new = [data_splt[i].split("'")[1:6:2] for i in range(len(data_splt))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works for me. I just didn't get the meaning of

Comment: .split("'")[1:6:2]. Could you please explain it to me.

Comment: Using `data_splt = data.split('\n')` gives you list of strings in format `"['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1']"`. Now, splitting them by `'` makes this another list, further split by apostrophe: `['[', 'DDD4', ', ', 'EEE4', ', ', 'AAA4', ']']`. We can see it has 7 elements (what we can check by using `len`), but the ones we are interested in are elements with indexes 1, 3 and 5. What `[1:6:2]` does is "take every index from 1 to 6 but in step of 2", which indeed makes us take the 1st, 3rd and 5th items in this list.

Comment: I get it .Thank you again!